# Disable html/javascripts commands in text fields

Tags: javascript, html, text, field

How do I prevent input in texts fields from containing HTML and JavaScript code?

Example: I have an input text field. If the user enters javascript instructions, then they get executed.

How can I modify

```
<script>alert('aces')</script>
```

so that it will show up as normal text in my field and not as a alert when i try to list it?

Comment: Where are you trying to list it? Are you intending the instructions to be executed, or is that a side-effect that you want to prevent? Do you have a code example you could post here?

Comment: @bucky24 

Im trying to prevent the user form doing that. 

Exampple: 

<input class="text" id ="nome" type="input"  value="" name="nome"/>

If i insert these lines, it will not see it as simple text, but as instructions, and this will mess up my page completly

<html><tr><td> fuuued up</td> </td></html> OR
<script>alert("jaeger bombs")</script>

Comment: When getting the value from an input, the value is a string by default. Where are you putting the value of what they enter?

Comment: Im putting the inputs on a Map<> to simulate a database. They will get erased after i shut down the servlet

Comment: You're fixing the wrong thing; it should be harmless for users to type HTML or JavaScript into a text field because you should **never execute user input**. If you're doing that you have bigger problems than users typing HTML in text fields.

Comment: How are you actually getting the input? You can target an input box and the value is a string by default. You can then enter that string into a database.

Comment: I made a deeper research and seems that i have to treat this problem on my servlet application with " escape jsp ", so < > will not get executed. I was trying to fix it in the html; when i would have to fix it on my servlet app

Answer (score 0):

Have you looked into libraries like underscore.js (used by Backbone.js)?

It comes with escape functions that prevents user entered javascript to run.
http://underscorejs.org/#escape and http://underscorejs.org/#unescape

so you would write:

alert(_.escape(USERINPUT));

this becomes even more important when you add user input to your DOM, for security reasons you need to escape inputs (or allow only a selection of harmless tags like < strong >).